# PhpStorm ignores PHP version setting in project

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I import two different projects to PhpStorm. After that, like always I need to switch PHP version for project from 5.3 to 5.5. After doing this I saved project.

When I reopen this project I see that PhpStorm don't save this setting. I do this same operation again. But again, after reopen project I need to set proper version for project.

I check xml files in `.idea` folder and php version is there set to 5.5.0 . I check `project.default.xml` and there php version is set to 5.5.0 too.

I reinstall PhpStorm using JetBrains Toolbox but this doesn't change anything.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 . My project files are in my `/home` folder and user/group of this is `www-data/www-data`. My user is in group `root/www-data/pmucha`. There is no problem with edit files (no permission problem).

I use latest version 2017.3.5 of PhpStorm.

I can't find solution to this problem. Can someone help me ?

I'm really tired of setting PHP version every time I open project or start new one.

Comment: is it possible that your project have some code deprecated in the target php version (5.5) so it assume that you've a 5.3 project?

Comment: this is not the problem. I fix all deprecated errors long time ago. Code is ready for 7.x ,but for month or two it will be still in 5.5. I don't want to switch for 7.x every time i reopen project.

Comment: which server are you using to test? Which php version do you have on this server?

Comment: Remember that PhpStorm displays the version of the PHP engine detected in the specified folder and the debugger associated with this PHP engine in the php.ini file. So you must have something wrong on there. For more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you have **composer.json** in these projects? Most likely yes.

Thing is: PhpStorm by default synchronizes some settings from composer.json file. It can sync your PHP Language Level as well as Source & Test roots.

Right now it looks like PHP version defined in composer.json is 5.3 or lower (5.3 is the lowest in PhpStorm) .. so PhpStorm resets your manually configured version to the provided one by composer.json. Such sync usually happens on project opening .. hence the feeling that IDE does not remember the settings.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/07/configuring-with-composer-in-phpstorm-2017-2/

**Two possible solutions:**

1. Either put a proper minimal PHP version into your composer.json (if you are writing your code using PHP 5.5 features .. so what's the point stating the 5.3 as lowest supported -- such code will fail if run using 5.3).

   For example (small part of `composer.json`):

   ```
   "require": {
       "php": ">=5.5",
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or disable such synchronisation at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Composer --> Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json`

[image]

Comment: that was it. Phpstorm take version from composer.json (i have php >= 5.3.9 ) and ignores my settings.